# Bootstrap Table All column not Showing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In Html,I have a table with 20 column, I want them to appear in a single view without using scroll bar to see all columns.I am using bootstrap as well.

[image]

Comment: show your relevant code please

Comment: Hi. Welcome to stackoverflow. First of all, it would be good if you can go through the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Secondly, it would be better if you can show what you've done in order to achieve this and what can the community assist to solve your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to add all those columns in different format maybe in horizontal fashion as this might affect the readability of table content. But you can follow this solution if changing layout is not an option for you.

```css
td,
th {
  display: inline-block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 5%!important; /*as total number of column is 20*/
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0;
}

th {
  height: 151px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Current Status</th>
        <th scope="col">Customer</th>
        <th scope="col">ORder Title</th>
        <th scope="col">Report Type</th>
        <th scope="col">Receive Date</th>
        <th scope="col">QA</th>
        <th scope="col">QA Time</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
        <th scope="col">QA Hold</th>
        <th scope="col">QC</th>
        <th scope="col">QC Time</th>
        <th scope="col">Delivered</th>
        <th scope="col">Delivered To(channel)</th>
        <th scope="col">DV V.</th>
        <th scope="col">Save Comments</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
        <th scope="col">Deviation Registration</th>
        <th scope="col">Deviation Report no</th>
        <th scope="col">Deviation Report</th>
        <th scope="col">Deviation Time</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not Solve . Again design issue

Comment: Kindly update that in your question or ask a separate one if its not related to this topic